# Reformat the SD card to install another OS on it

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I am trying to copy my newly built OS using Yocto into my raspberry SD card.
The SD card I am trying to use contains already other OS's for raspberry, so I think I need to reformat it before copying my new OS.
When I plug the SD card to my laptop two devices appear:
**/dev/mmcblk0p1**  and **/dev/mmcblk0p2** which one should I reformat ? and to which one should I copy the new OS?

I am using ubuntu 16.10

Comment: "When I plug the SD card to my laptop" that reminds me: unmount the partition(s) before reformat

Comment: If you're going to flash a new image, there's no need to reformat.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev
Can you explain to me why there is no need to reformat the SD card if I'm going to flash a new image? Because without reformating the SD, the rpi coudn't boot, what I did is : `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/dmmcblk0` Then I copied the new image `dd if=myImage.img of=/dev/zero bs=4M` 
seems like zero'ing the SD card is essential but I can understand whya

Comment: If reformatting is prerequisite, depends on the image. Standard Raspbian stretch image does not need a formatted medium and in this case zero'ing the SD card is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to which one should I copy the new OS

This depends a bit on where you are getting the new OS from, but most likely, neither.  Those are partitions on device `mmcblk0`, and that's where you want to put the new OS image. Raspberry Pi operating system images are, as a rule, device images which contain (at least) two partitions, and such an image must be copied to the SD card device, not one of the partitions on it, e.g.:

```
dd if=whatever.img of=/dev/mmcblk0
```

That said, if "my newly built OS using Yocto" is just a root filesystem, then you would want to recreate or delete the content from `mmcblk0p2` and copy in the content from the Yocto root fs.  However, there is a significant issue with that, namely that the kernel is loaded from the first partition and it will not match the available modules in the new root fs.

You could solve that by not deleting the old `/lib/modules` but I suspect this is not your scenario, since if you were trying to install a new root fs I do not think you would be asking this question.